# Javascript function does't return properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a javascript function  to validate a file input file :

```
function valaidateform() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');        
    message = "";
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;    

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();                  
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            filecontent =  reader.result.trim();
            var res = filecontent.split("\n");          
            lines = res.length;
            if (!(filecontent.substring(0, 1) == ">")) {
                alert("Not a proper file Fasta file");   
                return false;
            }
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);    
    } 
    else {
        alert("File not supported!");
    }

    alert("VAlidate function to end now")               
    return true;
}

//On form submit I call validateform() function
formrequest.submit(function() { 
    alert(valaidateform());
    if (validationstatus == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On my form submit code I call this function to check for file validation.Function is working properly as I can get alert message from function  but alert message `VAlidate function to end now` is shown before `Not a proper file Fasta file` and function always return true to caller function Why so? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileReader` executes asynchronously. This means that while the file is being read code execution continues on and hits your second `alert`. To stop this behaviour place all code reliant on the file reader within the `onload` handler:

```
if (file.type.match(textType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();                  
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        filecontent =  reader.result.trim();
        var res = filecontent.split("\n");          
        lines = res.length;
        if (!(filecontent.substring(0, 1) == ">")) {
            alert("Not a proper file Fasta file");   
        }

        alert("Validate function to end now") // note success alert placed here         

        // call a function here which handles the valid file result
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);    
} 
else {
    alert("File not supported!");
}
```

Note that you cannot return from an async handler. Instead you need to call a function to handle the result once the async function has completed.

Comment: Thank you for explaining cause to me , It really cleared reason for me but when I try same code in that case it returns undefined.